# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Connection must be valid and open

Tags: vb.net

### I'm trying to add values into database, but every time I try to add some thing i get an error in the ExecuteNonQuery() with the message "Connection must be valid and open." And I don't know what to do

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim ServerString As String = "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=root;Database=youtube"
    Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        SQLConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString

        Try
            If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then

                MsgBox("YAY! you are now connected")
            Else

                MsgBox("LOL Nope! you are not connected")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Unload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        SQLConnection.Close()
        SQLConnection.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SaveNames(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

        With cmd
            .CommandText = SQLStatement
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Connection = SQLConnection
            .ExecuteNonQuery() // keeps on saying System.InvalidOperationException: 'Connection must be valid and open.'

        End With

        SQLConnection.Close()
        MsgBox("YAY, you are now connected")
        SQLConnection.Dispose()

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
        Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO people(name) VALUES ('" & txtName.Text & "')"

        SaveNames(SQLStatement)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It's like you haven't read your own code.  Firstly, in your `Load` event handler, you check whether the connection's `State` is `Closed` and, if it is, you tell the user that they are connected.  Does that make sense?  Secondly, what's the point checking whether the connection is `Closed` when you know it will be because you have no code anywhere that actually opens it?

Comment: I really recommend that you do not create a single connection object like that.  You think you're doing the right thing but you're not and you've also managed to confuse yourself.  You should create a connection object each time you need one.  That way, there is no confusion about whether it's open or not.  You just created it so you know it's not, so you know you need to open it. If you create it with a `Using` statement then you know for a fact that it will be closed when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim ServerString As String = "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=root;Database=youtube"
    Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection(ServerString)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            SQLConnection.Open()
            If SQLConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed Then
                MsgBox("LOL Nope! you are not connected")
            Else
                MsgBox("YAY! you are now connected")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)

        End Try
        SQLConnection.Close()
        SQLConnection.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SaveNames(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(SQLStatement,SQLConnection)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("YAY, you are now connected")
        SQLConnection.Close()
        SQLConnection.Dispose()

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
        Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO people(name) VALUES ('" & txtName.Text & "')"

        SaveNames(SQLStatement)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Give this a try and let me know if it works, I did not test it But it should work.
You want to Open and Close Connections in the Methods making the call.
You don't want to open a connection when the form first loads, then leave it open until the form is closed, that is a bad practice.

For more information
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301075/how-to-connect-to-a-database-and-run-a-command-by-using-ado.net-and-visual-basic-.net

Also look into Using when doing Database access, this will close and dispose of the connections for you with out have to add code.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement

And try it in a Console App instead of a WinForm app, this will take some of the complexity out of the example before adding UI Problems.